# How to create a Multi-page app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-drawer, flutter-pagewise

This is a demo app from `https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer` where it shows an item of a list in the body of the new pages.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const appTitle = 'My Drawer App';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

... ... ... (more in https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer)
```

I want to be able to show text input fields and command button and process user input in each new pages. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn more about Flutter Navigations. Start from here with basic navigations : [Navigate to a new screen and back](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Once you become more experienced, I suggest learning and using the [Auto Router Package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) for Navigations.

Here, I'll show you how to achieve your requirement. But answers to these kinds of questions can be easily found on the internet.

First, you need to create a new screen:

```
 class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SecondScreen({super.key});

  // Add TextEditingController for the text input field
  final TextEditingController _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            // Add a text input field
            TextField(
              controller: _textFieldController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter text'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            // Add a command button
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Process user input, for example, print the entered text
                print(_textFieldController.text);
              },
              child: const Text('Process Input'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can navigate to that screen using Navigator.push():

```
// Within the `FirstRoute` widget
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen()),
  );
}
```

To return to the previous screen, you can use Navigator.pop():

```
// Within the SecondRoute widget
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```